# How can I change a variable to match a pandas dtype?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I would like a function that will determine the dtype of a pandas series, then change another variable to match that type, e.g. something like

```
def matchtype(pandas_series, variable):
    ...
    return variable_with_new_type
```

I can do the following:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> newtype = np.int64
>>> print(newtype)
<class 'numpy.int64'>
>>> print(newtype(3.0))
3
```

But it does not work with a dtype:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2]})
>>> newtype = df.a.dtype
>>> print(newtype)
int64
>>> print newtype(3.0)
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-5a5d48ddbb52> in <module>()
----> 1 print(newtype(3.0))

TypeError: 'numpy.dtype' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add an extra `.type` to get down to the underlying callable type beneath the numpy dtype object:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2]})
>>> newtype = df.a.dtype.type
>>> newtype
<class 'numpy.int64'>
>>> newtype(3.0)
3
>>> type(_)
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Comment: I suspected it would be something simple. Thank you.